# How to combine for loop values in one variable separated by comma [unix scripting]

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables, unix, scripting

I have this value: `123456`

and a for loop that trims the last digit:

1st iteration: `123456`

2nd iteration: `12345`

3rd iteration: `1234`

4th iteration: `123`

5th iteration: `12`

6th iteration: `1`

i would like the output to be stored in one variable

like this: `varA = 123456,12345,1234,123,12,1`

and like this: `varB = '123456','12345','1234','123','12','1'`

here's my code:

```
export input=$1
length=${#input}
j="$input"

for (( i=1, j=0; i<=length; i++, j=j+1 )); do
  len=$(echo "$((length-$j))")
  eachinput=$(echo ${input:0:$len})
  echo "each input : "$eachinput              #displays each trimmed value
done
```

Comment: This can be split into three "problems": (1) Before looping, you initialize the variable to the empty string. (2) In each iteration, you add the respective number and a comma. (3) When the loop is over, you have one extra comma at the end of the variable which you have to remove. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to do item (2), what is the syntax for that?

Comment: oh i got it! `allinput+="'${input}',"`

Answer (score 0):

before for loop:

`allinput=`

inside of for loop:

`allinput+="'${input}',"`

after for loop:

`allinput=${allinput%,}`

Answer (score 0):

Using substrings:

```sh
store_number_prefixes() {
  local -ir input="$1"
  local -n outputA="$2" outputB="$3"
  local slice
  local -i i
  outputA="$input"
  outputB="'${input}'"
  for ((i = -1; i > -${#input}; --i)); do
    slice="${input::i}"
    outputA+=",${slice}"
    outputB+=",'${slice}'"
  done
}

store_number_prefixes 123456 varA varB

echo "varA = ${varA}"
echo "varB = ${varB}"
```

Using arithmetics:

```sh
store_number_prefixes() {
  local -i input="$1"
  local -n outputA="$2" outputB="$3"
  outputA="$input"
  outputB="'${input}'"
  for ((input /= 10; input; input /= 10)); do
    outputA+=",${input}"
    outputB+=",'${input}'"
  done
}

store_number_prefixes 123456 varA varB

echo "varA = ${varA}"
echo "varB = ${varB}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to leverage arrays, and using `${foo[*]}` expansion to turn an array into a single string with elements separated by the value of `IFS`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add commas between elements of the array name given as the argument
commafy() {
    local -n arr="$1" # Nameref
    local IFS=,
    printf "%s\n" "${arr[*]}"
}

# Add quotes around elements and commas between the elements of the
# array name given as the argument.
# Note: Will break with spaces in array elements
quote_and_commafy() {
    local -n arr="$1"
    local -a quoted=( $(printf "'%s'\n" "${arr[@]}") )
    local IFS=,
    printf "%s\n" "${quoted[*]}"
}

input=123456
components=()

for (( i = ${#input}; i > 0; i-- )); do
    components+=(${input:0:i})
done

varA=$(commafy components)
varB=$(quote_and_commafy components)

printf "%s\n" "$varA" "$varB"
```